# State Updates After Second Load of componentWillReceiveProps and will not map

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am passing properties from a parent to the child and want to map the resulting array.

When I try to console log the result, the properties only reach after the second time the function is called. The first time it returns "[]". Even when the state "users" array is recieved, mapping it does nothing.

```
state={
    users: null
}

componentWillReceiveProps(){
    var userInLobby = this.props.users && this.props.users.map(userdata=>{
        if(userdata.status === "online"){
            var user = 
firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userdata.id).get().then(user=>{
                return {
                    username: user.data().username,
                };
            })
            return user

        }else{
            return null;
        }
        })
        var userInLobbyDisplay = []
        userInLobby && Promise.all(userInLobby).then(values => 
values.map(user=>{
            return userInLobbyDisplay.push(user)
        }))
        this.setState({
            users: userInLobbyDisplay
        })


}
render(){
console.log(this.state.users)
return(
<div className="lobby">
{
        this.state.users && this.state.users.map(user=>{
            return user.username
    })
}
</div>
)
```

How can I map the users array from the state to the DOM when receiving props for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a soon to be deprecated API, you should follow the documentation guidelines and switch to the newer APIs, specifically the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` You can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Your code here
  }
```