# Passing Prop from mapStateToProps to Dispatch Action is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-props

I am trying to Dispatch an Action with a value from mapStateToProps. The Error says:

*FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field xp)*

**Setup in main file:**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this.props.updateInLobby({ 
        userid: this.props.auth, 
        xp: this.props.user.xp,
        lobby: this.props.match.params.id,
}
...
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) =>{
    return{
        user: state.firebase.profile,
        auth: state.firebase.auth.uid,
    }
}
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        updateInLobby: (data) => {dispatch(updateInlobby(data))},
    }
}
export default compose(
     connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect((props)=>{
    return[
        {collection: "lobby@"+props.match.params.id}]
    })
)(RootLobby);
```

**Dispatch Action File:**

```
export const updateInlobby = (data) =>{
    return(dispatch, getState, {getFirestore}) =>{
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection("lobby@"+data.lobby).doc(data.userid).update({
            xp: data.xp
        })
    }
```

Why does userid and lobby seem to be defined as the document reference is working, but xp is undefined?

Comment: does `this.props.user` have property xp? Can you add a breakpoint and print `this.props.user` to check if it has any property xp.

Comment: Yes, when I console log this.props.user.xp it logs undefined the first time, but then logs the correct value

Comment: See my answer to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612053/state-updates-after-second-load-of-componentwillreceiveprops-and-will-not-map/54618959#54618959